# Modify request response before validation, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I get from response a formData, that I change into a middleware to use it on validation, the problem, is that I must do another modification to validate all elements from array without using '***array***.oneElement'.

**Code from Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->has('all_values')) {
        $request->merge([
            'all_values' => json_decode($request->get('all_values'), true)
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**// From Requst**

```
public function rules()
{
    $validations = [
        'all_values.saleforce_id'                    => 'required',
        'all_values.customer_id'                     => 'required',
        'all_values.lkp_product_category_id'         => 'required',
    ]
    // I need to access this all_values before validations

    if (request()->has('validation_field')) {
            return [request()->validation_field => $validations[ request()->validation_field ]];
        } // this is used for a validation , to do validation onChange

    return $validations;
}


  $request = $request->all()['all_values']; // I need something like this, but this doesn't work
```

Comment: No need for controller, for request the Request Resource is accessed first then the controller, and I need to modify the request before that, in middleware or in Request Resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `FormRequests` you can use `prepareForValidation()`.

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'all_values' => json_decode($request->get('all_values'), true),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Actually works for my validation method, but on submit I get error validation, like I have no field.

Comment: whats the difference between validation method and submit?